# Magento: send contact form with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

How can I edit the default Magento contact form to send email with jquery, without quitting the contact page ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Doesn't the form go back to the contact form page anyway? And what is wrong with the form submit and and validation classes that come with prototype? Are you wanting to do some ajax send instead?

Comment: I have modified the contact form to show it in popup window using the "facebox" jquery plugin. The problem with it is that It's closed when I submit the form, and I can see the validation message only when I open the contact form another time... Thanks for help :)

Comment: You could have used the window system that Magento has on the backend for the contacts form.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "window system" ? any example how to do that...?? just to send my form :)

Comment: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-pop-ups-with-window-js-in-the-front-end-with-magento/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overide the default behaviour off the form by doing something like this.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery("#formId").submit(function() { 

// run your code

return false;

});
```

The return false will prevent the form from posting

Comment: With prototype on the page you'll be needing noConflict jQuery( approach instead of $.

Comment: @Dominic Green : can you please clarify a little more what have I to write in my jQuery function ? Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: It depends what you are trying too do im a little confused what you need

Answer (score 0):

Prototype is still active on the page so you can probably use it anyway. Essentially you only need to change the submit button to an ordinary button that calls [`Form#request()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/prototype/request/)

```
<button title="Submit" class="button" onclick="this.form.request();">
    <span><span>Submit</span></span>
</button>
```